# How to build com dll with py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, win32com

I'm trying to convert my python project into an com dll using http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndWin32com

My `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys


class Target:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.__dict__.update(kw)
        # for the version info resources (Properties -- Version)
        self.version = "0.0.1"
        self.company_name = "my company"
        self.copyright = "© 2006, my company"
        self.name = "python server"


Test = Target(
    description="TestServer",
    # use module name for win32com exe/dll server
    modules=["test"],
    # specify which type of com server you want (exe and/or dll)
    create_exe=False,
    create_dll=True
    )

setup(
    name="TestServer",
    # the following two parameters embed support files within exe/dll file
    options={"py2exe": {"bundle_files": 1, }},
    zipfile=None,
    version="0.0.1",
    description="Python.TestServer",
    # author, maintainer, contact go here:
    author="First Last",
    author_email="some_name@some_company.com",
    com_server=[Test]
    )
```

After running `python setup.ty py2exe`, no dll is created in the dist directory

Doesn't Py2exeAndWin32com work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

support for win32com objects was removed
[albertosottile comment](https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe/issues/129#issuecomment-1121585455)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31855254)